# Java run code only if no exception is thrown in try and catch block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

How do I make it so the code runs only if there was no exception thrown?

With finally code runs whether there was an exception or not.

```
try {
   //do something
} catch (Exception e) {}
//do something only if nothing was thrown
```

Comment: Why not put it in the `try` block below the exception throwing call?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
try {
    somethingThatMayThrowAnException();
    somethingElseAfterwards();
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

Or if you want your second block of code to be outside the `try` block:

```
boolean success = false;
try {
    somethingThatMayThrowAnException();
    success = true;
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
if (success) {
    somethingElseAfterwards();
}
```

You could also put the `if` statement in a `finally` block, but there is not enough information in your question to tell if that would be preferable or not.

Comment: The first way is really the natural way to do. The second that introduces a local variable and a reading indirection brings no advantage here.

Comment: @davidxxx "brings no advantage" -- It depends on the use case. There are situations where you might want the second task to be executed outside the `try` block instead of inside. You might not want executions from the second block to be handled the same way as exceptions in the first block.

Answer (score 21):

```
try {
    doSomething();
    doSomething2();
} catch (Exception e) {
    doSomething3();
}
```

In this example, `doSomething2()` will only be executed if no exception is thrown by `doSomething()`.

If an exception is thrown by `doSomething()`, `doSomething2();` will be skipped and execution will jump to `doSomething3();`

Also note, `doSomething3()` will be executed if there is an exception thrown by `doSomething2();`

If no exception is thrown, `doSomething3();` will not be executed.

Comment: But what if `doSomething2` throws an exception? I don't want it to be catched.

Comment: So you'd want `doSomething2()` to stay in that order, but if it throws an exception it won't get caught and execute `doSomething3()`? You could place `doSomething2()` in a try catch block of its own (nested try block), and your catch could do nothing like `catch (Exception e) {}`.

Comment: I want to initialize some final value at `doSomething()`, and if exception is thrown, I then want the final value to hold some fall-back value. How to do that then?

Comment: If you want to change the value, it isn't final.

Comment: `try {
    doSomething1();
    doSomething2();
    doSomething3();
} catch (Exception e) {
    doSomething4();
}`  
@ThePerson I want to do someting like `doSomething1,2,3` execute only file all three have no exception how can I achive that?

Answer (score 5):

Just put the code in the `try` block.  If an exception is thrown, it will skip to the `catch` block.  If no exception is thrown, the code will just run.

```
try {
    someMethodThatMayThrowException();
    codeThatShouldBeRunIfNoExceptionThrown();
} catch (Exception e) {...}
```

Comment: Problem with this becomes: If `SomeException` is very general – if it could be thrown down the line by `codeThatShouldBeRunIfNoExceptionThrown`, or if that method changes to throw that exception in the future – then your catch block will (silently) no longer handle just the original exception.

Comment: @pathfinderelite You answer is fine (+1). I updated by focusing on the original requirement.

Answer (score 3):

An enhancement to the proposed

```
try {
    somethingThatMayThrowAnException();
    somethingElseAfterwards();
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

from the accepted answer. What you should do is:

```
void foo() {
  try {
    doStuff();
  } catch (...) {
    handleException();
  }
}
```

The above feels like overkill to someone who hasn't been exposed to "clean code thinking".

But the point here: you do **not** want to mix different abstractions within one method. In other words: you don't have one try block, and more code following behind that within the same method.

You make sure that each and any method contains a straight forward path - you avoid anything that complicates your reading flow. As soon as you get used to writing and reading *such* kind of code you will find that it takes you dramatically less time to understand your code.

Comment: Best part of the accepted answer (first part and not the second :)) with a bonus ! :)

Comment: @davidxxx Thanks. Always a pleasure hearing from you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions for flow control is kind of a bad practice. If you insist, use a `boolean` variable.

```
boolean thrown = false;

try {
   //do something
} catch (Exception e) {
   thrown = true;
}

//do something only if nothing was thrown

if (!thrown) { 
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this exact problem when I came across this question, and the answers here helped me think it through and realize, at least in my particular case, this was the wrong question I should have been asking.

I wanted to create this method because I was already doing it in main() and wanted to do it elsewhere for portability.  So I copied a block of code that contained a try/catch block.  However, it turns out, I don't want to copy the catch block at all, because if the creation of the Connection failed, I just wanted to fail completely.

It seems obvious now, but I never wanted to actually catch the exception in the first place.  That code was only there because I copy and pasted it.  So if you find yourself asking this question because you're in a try block and you might not generate a value, then consider if you just wanted to fail completely and not return anything that way this extra code is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the cleanest way to solve this, if you don't need the function to anything extra if an exception was raised, is return.

```java
try  {
    doSomthing();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    handleException();
    return;
}

onlyIfSuccess();
```