# How to print something only if an Exception is not raised?

Tags: java, try-catch, try-except

I am new to java but quite familiar with python. I was learning about try-catch blocks. I need to print something if there are no exceptions.

To do that in python we can use `else` with `try - except` block. I need to know what is the method that can be used in java to do this task.

Complete python code.

```
try:
    n = int(input())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("No exception is raised")
```

Incomplete java code to do the same thing.

```
import java.util.*;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = sc.nextInt();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        // need to add something
    }
}
```

Comment: you can declare a flag before the try and you can flip that flag inside the exception handler and check such flag outside the try block. Same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019453/java-run-code-only-if-no-exception-is-thrown-in-try-and-catch-block

Comment: Typically you add such an operation after the method that throws the exception. If an exception is thrown then the operation will be skipped because the catch block will execute instead.
Keep in mind you can extract to a method to keep the code well structured.
Don't introduce flags.

Comment: Agree with @NicoVanBelle, don't do any flags, that's how the `try` block would work, frankly I'm kinda surprised that Python has a mechanism for that case.

Comment: none of the comments addressed the fact that the op wants to know, after the try block, if the exception handler was run or not. If you don't use any flag you can't say what happened. The flag will be flipped INSIDE the catch ... and if no exception gets thrown that flag just doesn't get flipped. I agree it's a bad practice but yet it would require a totally different approach otherwise maybe too far from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write that code inside your finally block as below

```
import java.util.*;
    
    class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean excep = false;
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int n = sc.nextInt();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                excep = true;
            }
            finally{
               if(!excep){
                  System.out.println("no exceptions");
               }
            }
        }
    }
```